# Recovering the Jacobian directly from the complex derivative of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be entire. We can identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and "view" $f$ as a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by writing $f(z) = f(x + i y) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y)$. This allows one to derive the Cauchy-Riemann equations and identify the derivative $f'(z) \in \mathbb{C}$ with the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \partial_x u &  \partial_y u \\ - \partial_y u & \partial_x u \end{pmatrix}$, since $f'(z) = \partial_x u - i \partial_y u$.

Now, it is possible to define the bijection $\phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ as $\phi(x, y) = x + i y$ and then associating to $f$ the function $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f = \phi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}$. Then by using a sort of "chain rule", we have
$$
\underbrace{f'(z)}_{\in M_{1 \times 1}(\mathbb{C})} = \underbrace{D_{f(\phi^{-1}(x, y))} \phi}_{\in M_{1 \times 2} (\mathbb{C})} \cdot \underbrace{D_{\phi^{-1}(x, y)} F}_{\in M_{2 \times 2} (\mathbb{R})} \cdot \underbrace{D_{(x, y)} \phi^{-1}}_{\in M_{2 \times 1} (\mathbb{C})},
$$
which can be made to make sense by defining the matrices such that
$$
f'(z) = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1 & i\end{pmatrix}}_{D_{f(\phi^{-1}(x, y))} \phi} \cdot \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \partial_x u &  \partial_y u \\ - \partial_y u & \partial_x u \end{pmatrix}}_{D_{\phi^{-1}(x, y)} F} \cdot \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}}_{D_{(x, y)} \phi^{-1}} = \partial_x u - i \partial_y u. \tag{1}\label{eq:1}
$$

I don't have a justification for the values of $D_{f(\phi^{-1}(x, y))} \phi$ and $D_{(x, y)} \phi^{-1}$ (I don't know of any definitions for the derivative of a $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ function), it just happens to work out. However, I am struggling to do the opposite, so using $F = \phi^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi$ to determine the Jacobian of $F$. The idea is again to apply some kind of "chain rule" to $D_{(x, y)} F$ and recover the Jacobian directly from $f'(z)$ without defining $u$ and $v$. The problem is, I can't find a way to define this "chain rule". It would have to go something like
$$\underbrace{D_{(x, y)} F}_{\in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})} = \underbrace{D_{f(\phi(x, y))} \phi^{-1}}_{\in M_{2 \times 1} (\mathbb{C})} \cdot \underbrace{D_{\phi(x, y)} f}_{\in M_{1 \times 1} (\mathbb{C})} \cdot \underbrace{D_{(x, y)} \phi}_{\in M_{1 \times 2} (\mathbb{C})},
$$
where $D_{\phi(x, y)} f = f'(\phi(x, y))$. The point is that the resulting matrix would be
$$
D_{(x, y)} F = \begin{pmatrix} \Re(f'(\phi(x, y))) &  - \Im(f'(\phi(x, y))) \\ \Im(f'(\phi(x, y))) & \Re(f'(\phi(x, y))) \end{pmatrix}.
$$
But it seems to be impossible to choose $D_{f(\phi(x, y))} \phi^{-1}$ and $D_{(x, y)} \phi$ such that this is true, the matrices from \eqref{eq:1} don't work.

Am I missing something small or am I on the completely wrong track?

Comment: For "$D\phi$", what you're seeing is that $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to V$ canonically correspond to $(1 \times n)$ matrices with entries in $V$, whereas the $D\phi^{-1}$ matrix should really be written $(\Re, \Im)^t$, ie a $2 \times 1$ matrix with entries in $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into something subtle. $\phi$ is a linear map so it's equal to its own derivative everywhere, that isn't the issue. The real issue is how to express $\phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ and $\phi^{-1} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ as matrices. For $\phi$ it is actually not a problem: $\phi$ satisfies, by definition,

$$\phi \left[ \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right] = x + iy$$

so it can be represented by left multiplication by the matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & i \end{array} \right]$, which you've used. Abstractly we are saying that we have an isomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}^2$. More generally we have a natural isomorphism $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}^n, V) \cong V^n$ for any real vector space $V$.

The problem is $\phi^{-1}$, because it is supposed to take in complex numbers and return real ones. $\phi^{-1}$ satisfies, by definition,

$$\phi^{-1}(z) = \left[ \begin{array}{c} \text{Re}(z) \\ \text{Im}(z) \end{array} \right]$$

so it actually cannot be represented by multiplication by a matrix of numbers at all; we actually need to talk about the real and imaginary parts as two linear functionals on $\mathbb{C}$, as ronno says in the comments. Abstractly we are saying that we have an isomorphism $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}^2) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R})^2$ but $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R})$ does not simplify further; it is a $2$-dimensional vector space with a basis given by the real and imaginary parts and that's all.

So your first calculation in (1) used the wrong matrix for $\phi^{-1}$ and worked by accident. The correct calculation is as follows:

$$f'(z) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & i \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \partial_x u & \partial_x v \\ \partial_y u & \partial_y v \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \text{Re} \\ \text{Im} \end{array} \right]$$

where $\text{Re}$ and $\text{Im}$ are not numbers but linear functionals $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$. This says that if $w$ is another complex number then

$$f'(z) w = \left( \partial_x u + i \partial_y u \right) \text{Re}(w) + \left( \partial_x v + i \partial_y v \right) \text{Im}(w)$$

which is true. To recover the Jacobian from the complex derivative we multiply in the other direction, getting

$$Df = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \text{Re} \\ \text{Im} \end{array} \right] f'(z) \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & i \end{array} \right].$$

This gives

$$Df = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \text{Re}(f') & \text{Re}(if') \\ \text{Im}(f') & \text{Im}(if') \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \text{Re}(f') & -\text{Im}(f') \\ \text{Im}(f') & \text{Re}(f') \end{array} \right]$$

as expected.